# R and bioconductor, why is the getGEO() function generating the error "Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404"?

Tags: r, http, http-status-code-404, bioconductor

I am using R (version 3.4.4) on a computer running Linux Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.
I am trying to download a dataset from [Gene Expression Omnibus (GEO)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi) with the  function [getGEO()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/GEOquery/versions/2.38.4/topics/getGEO) of the bioconductor package [GEOquery](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GEOquery.html).
The dataset GEO code is [GSE134381](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE134381).

Unexpectedly, the getGEO() generates an HTTP error 404. How to fix it?

I am using the following R commands:

```
setwd(".")
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("GEOquery")
library(GEOquery)

GSE_code <- "GSE134381"
gset <- getGEO(GSE_code, GSEMatrix =TRUE, getGPL=FALSE)
```

and it generates the following error:

> Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404.

How to solve this problem? Why is it happening?

Thanks!

**EDITED**: corrected link to GEO dataset

Comment: Seems like the data that the query is trying to access is no longer there. You can try raising an issues with the package author: https://github.com/seandavi/GEOquery/issues. It might just be a temporary server issues.

Comment: setting `GSEMatrix = FALSE` worked for me

Comment: also your link leads to a different dataset